# Can MS Project graph out planned value?

Tags: ms-project, tools, evm

I would like to create a graph like the one below dynamically in Project. I have done this in the past using Excel, but in those cases it was "easy" since planned and earned value were calculated based on contractual milestone payments on a FFP contract. For my current projects this isn't possible, instead any earned value analysis would be based on percentage of work completed and level of effort contributed by internal resources.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it does.  MS Project is seriously limited in its functionality.  On our EVMS solution, we only load our schedule in project; our dollars are loaded into another tool and even a third tool is used to draw the graphs, called Winsight.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy but you have to do it in a weird way.

1. Go to Reports - Visual Reports
2. Select New Template, Excel, Assignment Usage, and click OK.

Your report is now being created in Excel.  Switch over to Excel.

1. Add Time Weekly Calendar to the Row Labels section.
2. Check Cumulative Work, Actual Work and Baseline Work.
3. Move Values to the Column Labels box.

Then you have all the data you want to manipulate and create your chart.